# Continuous UI activity and frequent NSTimer calls

Tags: ios, multithreading, user-interface, nstimer

My app has quite a lot of continuous UI changes at times and I also need to run an `NSTimer` that calls a selector every 0.01 seconds which updates a progress view (not the standard iOS progress view) in order for it to appear animated.

However, as both are running on the main thread, the UI activity is halting the NSTimer all the time.

I've tried the following:

```
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.myTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

but still no luck.

Looked into using GCD but that's no good for such short intervals.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to this in order to allow the continuous UI updates and also allow the progress view to appear animated?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to update your progress view every 10 ms? This is at a 100 Hz rate. Nobody can see this. Maybe you try it with 30 Hz?

Comment: I did think it was a little extreme actually. Just tried at 30Hz and it's still halting enough to be noticeable.